# Git erased my changes, can I get them back

Tags: git, github-for-mac

I had some changes in a branch, we'll call it branch2. I switched to the master branch without committing the changes. I'm guessing this is a no-no because when I switched back to branch2 all of my change were gone! It sure would have been nice if the GitHub client for mac would have warned me. Is there anyway I can undo this action and get my changes back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it wasn't committed, then there's nothing to do. Although, this is weird because normally git won't allow you to switch branch if you have uncommitted data in your working directory (I don't know for github for mac exactly).

You can always check `git reflog` to see if you have committed your data.

Comment: The Github client for Mac usually pushes and pops a stash when you change branches. I guess something went wrong.

Comment: Then you should at least check in your stash `git stash list`. Maybe it's in there, but that's kind of a weird behavior from the git client, and seems like error prone to me. I'm sometime using github for windows and it didn't seems like acting this way (I would have expected same git workflow on both platform, seems like it's not!)

Comment: Right on, get confused by stackoverflow haha!