# Lost commits made to git on switching branch

Tags: git, github

I have just started using git and am not aware of may be some basic functionalities of it. I cloned a forked repo on my machine and started making changes to the repo without taking a note of the branch I was using. I assumed it must be some default. I committed the change and then selected current branch as master from the GitHub UI interface on OSx. Now when I see my repo, I don't see any of my changes in it. Instead the recent commits are by the original authors of the repo.

PS. I had not published the committed changes

Comment: Check the other branches to see which branch your changes are on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git reflog` 
is what you need. It shows you the log of local "ref" changes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657815/git-erased-my-changes-can-i-get-them-back

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using `git reflog` this might solve you issue
2. Know your commits by using `git log Head@{Id}`
3. If you get head Id which has the commits you require then give the cmd `git reset Head@{Id which has the commits}`